DateTimeUtils.lastDay(int) and SqlTypeName problem
My Calcite based application works well with calcite-core 1.20 and avatica-core 1.22, but when I tried to upgrade calcite-core to version 1.35 (with avatica-core1.22), the application failed due to absence of the
org.apache.calcite.avatica.util.DateTimeUtils.lastDay(int) method, the detailed messages are as following:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-11-02 17:53:07.280 ERROR [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication-- Application run failed
......
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.calcite.avatica.util.DateTimeUtils.lastDay(int)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
at org.apache.calcite.linq4j.tree.Types.lookupMethod(Types.java:309)
... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while preparing statement [select sum(case when temp_cntdpd_m24 > 0 and temp_cntdpd_m06 > 0 and temp_cntdpd_m24 = temp_cntdpd_m06 then 1 else null end) as CDACCT24T06R9 from GAA02_CREDITINFO_MIDDLE where account_type <> 'C1' and currency_type = 'CNY']
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:220)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:202)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:178)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while applying rule AggregateCaseToFilterRule, args [rel#38126:LogicalAggregate.NONE., rel#38124:LogicalProject.NONE.[](input=RelSubset#38123,exprs=[CASE(AND(>($3, 0), >($2, 0), =($3, $2)), 1, null:INTEGER)])]
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoRuleCall.onMatch(VolcanoRuleCall.java:256)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.IterativeRuleDriver.drive(IterativeRuleDriver.java:58)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.findBestExp(VolcanoPlanner.java:510)
at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs.lambda$standard$3(Programs.java:271)
at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs$SequenceProgram.run(Programs.java:331)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.optimize(Prepare.java:166)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:297)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:208)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:632)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:498)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:468)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:231)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:213)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.intValue(RexLiteral.java:1102)
at org.apache.calcite.rel.rules.AggregateCaseToFilterRule.transform(AggregateCaseToFilterRule.java:231)
at org.apache.calcite.rel.rules.AggregateCaseToFilterRule.onMatch(AggregateCaseToFilterRule.java:115)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoRuleCall.onMatch(VolcanoRuleCall.java:229)
... 27 more


And when I try to use calcite-core 1.38.0 and avatica-core 1.25.0 , I got another error like this:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: while converting METHOD4('MS_P2_PDD_MONTH_MAX', T1.ACCOUNT_TYPE, METHOD2('MS_P2_REPAY_STATE_5Y_PARSE', T1.ACCOUNT_TYPE, T4.REPAY_STATE_5Y), CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST(METHOD6('MS_P2_DIV', MS_P2_TS_INTERVAL_DAY(CASE WHEN T0.TIME_RECT IS NOT NULL THEN T0.TIME_RECT ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN T2.INFO_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN T2.INFO_DATE ELSE NULL END), 30, NULL, NULL, NULL, 6) AS DOUBLE)) AS INTEGER) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(METHOD6('MS_P2_DIV', MS_P2_TS_INTERVAL_DAY(CASE WHEN T0.TIME_RECT IS NOT NULL THEN T0.TIME_RECT ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN T2.INFO_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN T2.INFO_DATE ELSE NULL END), 30, NULL, NULL, NULL, 6) AS DOUBLE)) AS INTEGER) END, 3)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:147)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.lambda$new$11(StandardConvertletTable.java:288)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectList(SqlToRelConverter.java:4744)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:814)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:734)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3905)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2483)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2393)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2355)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:754)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:734)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3905)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:627)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:257)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:220)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:673)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:524)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:492)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:237)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:217)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:142)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Was not expecting value 'OTHER' for enumeration 'org.apache.calcite.sql.type.SqlTypeName' in this context
at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.unexpected(Util.java:1937)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.valueMatchesType(RexLiteral.java:398)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.canRemoveCastFromLiteral(RexBuilder.java:860)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.makeCast(RexBuilder.java:767)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.makeCast(RexBuilder.java:647)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.ensureType(RexBuilder.java:1551)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.lambda$convertOperands$22(StandardConvertletTable.java:1210)
at org.apache.calcite.util.Pair.forEach(Pair.java:282)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1209)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1194)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertFunction(StandardConvertletTable.java:941)
... 48 more
com.[java class name omitted]: init error
at [java class name omitted]
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while preparing statement [
SQL omitted
...
]
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:102)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:178)

... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: while converting METHOD2('CM_MAX_NUMBER_2', CAST(METHOD4('MS_P2_PDD_MONTH_MAX', B.ACCOUNT_TYPE, G.PARSE_REPAY_STATE_5Y, F.MONTHOFFSET, 3) AS INTEGER), F.TEMPNEWPD)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:147)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertCast(StandardConvertletTable.java:739)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.lambda$new$11(StandardConvertletTable.java:288)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectList(SqlToRelConverter.java:4744)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:814)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:734)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3905)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:627)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:257)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:220)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:673)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:524)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:492)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:237)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:217)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:142)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: while converting METHOD4('MS_P2_PDD_MONTH_MAX', B.ACCOUNT_TYPE, G.PARSE_REPAY_STATE_5Y, F.MONTHOFFSET, 3)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:147)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertCast(StandardConvertletTable.java:739)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1202)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1194)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertFunction(StandardConvertletTable.java:941)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:142)
... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Was not expecting value 'OTHER' for enumeration 'org.apache.calcite.sql.type.SqlTypeName' in this context
at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.unexpected(Util.java:1937)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.valueMatchesType(RexLiteral.java:398)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.canRemoveCastFromLiteral(RexBuilder.java:860)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.makeCast(RexBuilder.java:767)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.makeCast(RexBuilder.java:647)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.ensureType(RexBuilder.java:1551)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.lambda$convertOperands$22(StandardConvertletTable.java:1210)
at org.apache.calcite.util.Pair.forEach(Pair.java:282)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1209)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1194)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertFunction(StandardConvertletTable.java:941)
... 66 more
2024-11-03 10:30:21.975 ERROR [main]
...
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
at [omitted]
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
at [omitted]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289)


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)

at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by:
... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while preparing statement [
SQL ommitted
...
]
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:102)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:178)
at
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: while converting METHOD4('MS_P2_PDD_MONTH_MAX', T1.ACCOUNT_TYPE, METHOD2('MS_P2_REPAY_STATE_5Y_PARSE', T1.ACCOUNT_TYPE, T4.REPAY_STATE_5Y), CASE WHEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST(METHOD6('MS_P2_DIV', MS_P2_TS_INTERVAL_DAY(CASE WHEN T0.TIME_RECT IS NOT NULL THEN T0.TIME_RECT ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN T2.INFO_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN T2.INFO_DATE ELSE NULL END), 30, NULL, NULL, NULL, 6) AS DOUBLE)) AS INTEGER) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(METHOD6('MS_P2_DIV', MS_P2_TS_INTERVAL_DAY(CASE WHEN T0.TIME_RECT IS NOT NULL THEN T0.TIME_RECT ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN T2.INFO_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN T2.INFO_DATE ELSE NULL END), 30, NULL, NULL, NULL, 6) AS DOUBLE)) AS INTEGER) END, 3)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:147)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.lambda$new$11(StandardConvertletTable.java:288)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.convertCall(SqlNodeToRexConverterImpl.java:61)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5972)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.visit(SqlToRelConverter.java:5115)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:168)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter$Blackboard.convertExpression(SqlToRelConverter.java:5786)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectList(SqlToRelConverter.java:4744)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:814)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:734)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3905)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2483)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2393)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2355)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:754)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:734)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3905)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:627)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:257)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:220)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:673)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:524)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:492)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:237)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.prepareStatement_(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:217)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.ReflectiveConvertletTable.lambda$registerOpTypeMethod$3(ReflectiveConvertletTable.java:142)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Was not expecting value 'OTHER' for enumeration 'org.apache.calcite.sql.type.SqlTypeName' in this context
at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.unexpected(Util.java:1937)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.valueMatchesType(RexLiteral.java:398)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.canRemoveCastFromLiteral(RexBuilder.java:860)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.makeCast(RexBuilder.java:767)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.makeCast(RexBuilder.java:647)
at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexBuilder.ensureType(RexBuilder.java:1551)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.lambda$convertOperands$22(StandardConvertletTable.java:1210)
at org.apache.calcite.util.Pair.forEach(Pair.java:282)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1209)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertOperands(StandardConvertletTable.java:1194)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.StandardConvertletTable.convertFunction(StandardConvertletTable.java:941)
... 48 more```

